# Add the JavaScript language hint to the `reactjs` and `react-jsx` tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, syntax-highlighting

Since [React is a JavaScript library](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/reactjs/info), questions that are tagged [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) or [react-jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-jsx) should utilize JavaScript syntax highlighting by default. Even in cases where React is used in a non-browser environment, JavaScript is still the driving language unless a compile-to-JS language (such as CoffeeScript or TypeScript) is used.

The JavaScript syntax highlighter seems to handle JSX syntax correctly in all the cases I've seen:

```js
// Some JSX

import { Component } from "react";

class CommentForm extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var author = this.refs.author.value.trim();
    var text = this.refs.text.value.trim();
    if (!text || !author) {
      return;
    }
    // TODO: send request to the server
    this.refs.author.value = '';
    this.refs.text.value = '';
    return;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form className="commentForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        {/* a JSX comment */
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your name" ref="author" />
        <span {...propsSpread, { testing: "true" }} />
        <SubComponent props={this.props.sub}>
          <Modal {...modalProps}>
        </SubComponent>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm not certain that every [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) question should also be tagged [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) since some questions and answers have little to do with JavaScript directly, but more to do with how the library behaves.

Comment: "Correctly" is subjective; the HTML fragments aren't really highlighted at all.

Comment: @Makoto Fair, but (and maybe this is just my opinion), it's better than any of the other syntaxes, and certainly much better than none at all.

Comment: @Gimby but typescript [uses JS highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/typescript/info#prev-value) anyway. There are still [35,458](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs+-javascript+-typescript) react questions not tagged with {java,type}script out of [68,404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) react questions in total.

Comment: @Al.G. thank you for bringing up that old comment, I no longer support that opinion. Languages should only be tagged when the question is about the language.

Comment: How do we encourage some activity/consideration from SO developers on this request? This seems like a sensible and safe assumption, with a straightforward solution.

Comment: Not sure why this is still undone after 3 years, because syntax highlighting still doesn't work on questions without the `javascript` tag.