# Set lang-js as the default syntax highlighting for [react-native]

Tags: feature-request, tags, syntax-highlighting

[React Native](https://reactnative.dev) code is basically [React](https://reactjs.org) code, so I'm extending an old request that was made for React ([Add the JavaScript language hint to the `reactjs` and `react-jsx` tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307863/8839059)) to React Native.

Can we have `lang-js` as the default syntax highlighting for [react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-native)?

An example code with JS syntax highlighting:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Switch } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(false);
  return (
    <Switch style={styles.switch} value={value} onValueChange={setValue} />
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  switch: {
    margin: 30,
  },
});
```

Comment: The way that tags interact with syntax highlighting can be more complicated than it first appears, especially when tags with different highlighter hints are often combined together, but it seems pretty clean cut in this case. [[tag:react-native]] is a JavaScript library– it should default highlight code as JS. It's worth noting though that posts which are also tagged as either [[tag:javascript]] or [[tag:reactjs]] _already_ get `lang-js` as their default from those tags.